# $.get не работает, хотя .load отрабатывает

Tags: jquery, ajax

Был у меня такой код:

```
$('#win_fog').fadeIn('fast').find('#cont').load('htmls/user.html');
```

И он работал. Затем мне понадобилось загружать сразу много страниц в один блок и код я усовершенствовал вместе с древом каталогов:

```
path='htmls/user/';
$.when($.get(path+'general.html'),$.get(path+'profile.html')).then(function(a,b){alert(a[0]+b[0])});
```

Но алерта не следовало. Я протестировал `$.get` функцию простым запросом и оказалось, что он виновник:

```
$.get('htmls/user/general.html',function(data){alert(data)});
```

ибо ничего не происходит. В консоле только надоедливая ошибка: `Ошибка синтаксического анализа XML:`, но `.load()` функции она не мешала. Что здесь не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, сервер отдаёт html таким образом, что jQuery его понимает как xml, парсит неправильным способом и падает. Попробуй указать `dataType`:

```
var path = 'htmls/user/';

$.when(
  $.get({url: path+'general.html', dataType: 'html' }),
  $.get({url: path+'profile.html', dataType: 'html' })
).then(function (a, b) {
  alert(a[0]+b[0])
});
```

Comment: Да, так заработало. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать вот так:

```
$.get('htmls/user/general.html', {}, function(data) {alert(data)});
```

Так как 2-ой параметр это массив с данными.

Comment: Уже пробовал, не помогает.

Comment: можеш кинуть адрес полний с доменом @Diskyp Может надо с слеша начать

Comment: В адресе-то я уверен, так как `.load('htmls/user/general.html')` отрабатывает как надо. Ну и со слешем и с точкой+слешем я тоже уже попробовал, не помогает.

Comment: постав все таки слеш в начале так как ето относительний путь(Ето не к теме)

Comment: `jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )` - все параметры кроме адреса необязательны: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/